# Difference between s[s].index and s.index where s is a Series

Tags: python

`s` is a `Series` with following values

```
Id               False
MSSubClass       False
MSZoning          True
LotFrontage      False
LotArea          False
Street            True
Alley             True
LotShape          True
LandContour       True
Utilities         True
```

If I print `s.index`, I get all indexes `(Id, MSSubClass ...)`. This makes sense. But if I do `s[s].index` then I get only those indexes whose value is true.

Why? How is `s[s]` interpreted?

Comment: happy to accept your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`s` is a series with bool values and `s[s]` is a shortcut for `s[s==True]` which is a slicing method.